# Where can I find this line of code getWindow().setFlags (WindowManager.FLAG_SECU RE, WindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);

Tags: android, decoding

I want to disable flag secure in a particular application after searching I got to know this is the line of code I need to remove.....

getWindow().setFlags (WindowManager.FLAG_SECU RE, WindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);

I am not a programmer or anything no knowledge just a beginner by myself. I don't know where can I find this line of code I checked in androidmenifest.xml but there's nothing. If someone is explaining can you please tell me that after removing this line of code I will be able to screen recording of that application right? Nothing more I have to do? Just remove this line of code?

I tried taichi application too it worked in other applications like jio tv, Remini etc but not in that application. I think The reason behind it can be that application stores id of my phone or imei number at their server and you guys know taichi run its pached application on their platform that's why my application recognise it and error comes out. Now you may know that if I try to download that application in another phone (rooted/nonrooted) and login with my phone number it shows error...
Conclusion- I can't login in another phone with same login id ...the phone must be same which I used to create login id and pass in the beginning....HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use getActivity() or requireActivity() before.getWindow()
```

> this getActivity() will return the Activity this fragment is currently
> associated with.

##### Example from Activity

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags (WindowManager.FLAG_SECU RE, WindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

##### Example from Fragment

```
requireActivity().getWindow().setFlags (WindowManager.FLAG_SECU RE, WindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those lines should usually be applied in an `Application` class if the whole app can't be screen recorded. If only certain screens are secured, check the `Activity` or `Fragment` classes.

Despite all that, you can just use the software [srcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) on your PC to connect your phone and screen record it even when `FLAG_SECURE` is set.

Comment: As you said I tried scrcpy from GitHub and first tried to screen recording of incognito mode and it's showing nothing but black screen.

Comment: Going with your first method- you asked if the whole application is preventing screen record. Answer is I start screen recording and open that application I enter sever name and login id password as I start playing videos screen recording shows black screen. Basically it's an application for education we can watch lecture videos through this app. This fu**in application is more secured than nasa security system. It recognises usb debugging is on or not and says to turn it off.